# Proof that $\frac{\log x}{x^\alpha} \to 0 \;\; \forall \alpha>0$ by integral definition of $\log$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

As a proof that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\log x}{x^\alpha} = 0 \;\;\;\;\;\forall \alpha >0$$

an author offers the following proof: for $x>1$,

$$\log x = \int_1^x \frac1\xi d\xi < \int_1^x \xi^{\epsilon -1} d\xi = \frac1\epsilon (x^\epsilon-1),$$

then we divide both sides by $x^\alpha$ (setting $\epsilon = \alpha$) and this shows that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\log x}{x^\alpha} = 0$.

**My Question:** I'm not seeing how it establishes the claim. I think he means by the squeeze theorem, except it would seem that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}\epsilon \frac{x^\epsilon-1}{x^\alpha} = \frac1\epsilon,$$

not zero as we would want in the squeeze theorem. Can anyone parse this?

Comment: I believe that $\epsilon$ is supposed to be arbitrarily small...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon=\frac{\alpha}{2}$. Then the argument shows that 
$$\log x \lt \frac{2}{\alpha} (x^{\alpha/2}-1).$$
Divide both sides  by $x^\alpha$ and let $x\to\infty$.

Comment: OK. Perhaps the setting $\epsilon = \alpha$ is a typo... Thanks.